# python search and extract list in list which are not there

Tags: python-3.x, list, nested, extract

I have two lists

```
a = [[a1,b1],[a2,b2], [a3,b3],[a4,b4],[a5,b5]]
b = [[a1,b1],[a2,b2],[d3,e3],[c4,d4]]
```

How do I run loop to get all values which do not match
Result = [[a3,b3],[a4,b4],[a5,b5],[d3,e3],[c4,d4]

I am able to get matching ones

```
answer = [[a1,b1],[a2,b2]] since both are matching.
```

How do I get the mismatched ones. if possible two separate lists of

```
result1 =  [a3,b3],[a4,b4],[a5,b5]
result2 = [d3,e3],[c4,d4]
```

I am using python3.6

Thanks
Tom

Comment: `result1=a not in b` and `result2= b not in a`

Comment: its a nested list. How do I compare? How do I write loop?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write two different for loops as below:

```
result1=[]
result2=[]
for i in a:
    if i not in b:
        result1.append(i)

for j in b:
    if j not in a:
        result2.append(j)

print(result1, result2)
```

Output

```
[['a3', 'b3'], ['a4', 'b4'], ['a5', 'b5']] [['d3', 'e3'], ['c4', 'd4']]
```